# jQuery, make dropdown menu hide when click elsewhere

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using jQuery to make a simple drop down menu:

```
<script>                    
  $("#optionsLink").click(function(){                   
    $("#optionsMenu").slideToggle();
  });
</script>
```

It works fine but I would like the menu to disappear when the user clicks elsewhere on the screen. A bit like your standard windows drop down menu. Clicking on "File" in my browser will display the drop down menu but clicking somewhere else, anywhere on a page for example, will hide the menu.

How would I go about implementing something like this?

Comment: can you share the HTML of the menu, and related CSS / JS ?  A jsfiddle would be great! http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @msturdy There's really no need to show HTML because one can infer that `#optionsMenu` is the menu and the rest of the question just refers to jQuery.

Comment: Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
$("#optionsLink").click(function(e){
  $("#optionsMenu").slideToggle();
  e.stopPropagation(); 
});

$(document).click(function(){                   
  $("#optionsMenu").slideUp();
});
```

"slideToggle" would toggle the menu every time you click anywhere and I don't think that's what you want

`.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up to the document when you click inside of the `#optionsLink`

Comment: Your solution works, but clicking within #optionsMenu also slides #optionMenu up. How could I change that to "document except #optionsMenu".click -> slideUp ?

Comment: just use `stopPropagation` on `$('#optionsMenu')` as well

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#optionsLink").click(function(){                   
    $("#optionsMenu").slideToggle();
  });
//new part
$(':not(#optionsLink, #optionsLink *)').click(function() {
    $("#optionsMenu").slideUp();
});
```

Targeting `#optionsLink` means you just have one drop-down. If you would have more you should hava class instead, maybe like `.optionsLink`.

Comment: I tried your proposed solution, but now when I click on #optionsLink it displays #optionsMenu but #optionsMenu automatically slides up as soon as it's finished sliding down. I'm very new to jQuery, but doesn't your code tell him to slide up when #optionsLink is not being clicked?

Comment: @user2018084, the `:not(#optionsLink)` means all elements besides `#optionsLink`. Try my updated answer.